# Improve performance of constraint-adding in Gurobi (Python-Interface)

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, gurobi

i got this decision variable:

```
x={}
for j in range(10):
    for i in range(500000):
        x[i,j] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%d%d" %(i,j))
```

so i need to add constraints for each x[i,j] variable like this:

```
for p in range(10):
    for u in range(500000):
        m.addConstr(x[u,p-1]<=x[u,p])
```

this is taking me so much time, more that 12hrs and then a lack of memory pop-up appears at my computer.
Can someone helpme to improve this constraint addition problem

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error when you index with p=0 and p-1.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you are running out of physical memory and using virtual (swap) memory.  This would not cause your computer to report an out-of-memory warning or error.

I rewrote your code as follows:

```
from gurobipy import *

m = Model()

x={}
for j in range(10):
  for i in range(500000):
    x[i,j] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%d%d" %(i,j))
m.update()

for p in range(10):
  for u in range(500000):
    try:
      m.addConstr(x[u,p-1]<=x[u,p])
    except:
      pass
m.update()
```

I tested this using Gurobi Optimizer 6.5.2 on a computer with an Intel Xeon E3-1240 processor (3.40 GHz) and 32 GB of physical memory.  It was able to formulate the variables and constraints in 1 minute 14 seconds. You might be able to save a small amount of memory using a list, but I believe that Gurobi Var and Constr objects require far more memory than a Python dict or list.

Comment: thanks Greg Glockner, now understanding that the problem is because the lack of memory, do you know if Gurobi can be executed with GPU programming?t

Comment: @jmparejaz Gurobi does not support GPU programming yet (and maybe not in the near future). Ignoring a lot of stuff which could be said about the problems being solved with Gurobi and GPU-approaches therefore, just let me tell you, that with GPU-programming, usually memory is just an even bigger problem (especially in Deep-Learning; GPU-memory in general more expensive than main-memory). It's quite cheap to obtain 32GB memory for a workstation, a 32GB GPU will be very expensive (if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

### General Remark:

- It looks quite costly to add 5 million constraints in general

### Specific Remark:

#### Approach

- You are wasting time and space by using *dictionaries*

  - Despite having constant-access complexity, these constants are big
  - They are also wasting memory
- In a simple 2-dimensional case like this: stick to arrays!

#### Validity

- Your indexing is missing the border-case of the first element, so indexing breaks!

Try this (much more efficient approach; using numpy's arrays):

```
import numpy as np
from gurobipy import *

N = 10
M = 500000

m = Model("Testmodel")
x = np.empty((N, M), dtype=object)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        x[i,j] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%d%d" %(i,j))
m.update()

for u in range(M):  # i switched the loop-order
    for p in range(1,N):  # i'm handling the border-case
        m.addConstr(x[p-1,u] <= x[p,u])
```

**Result:**

- *~2 minutes*
- *~2.5GB* memory (complete program incl. Gurobi's internals)

Comment: Thanks Sascha I will try this inmediately

Comment: numpy is not helpful in this case: most of the memory is taken by the Gurobi Var and Constr objects.

Comment: @GregGlockner numpy surely is more memory-efficient as a dictionary (and of course it's faster to index). But of course you are right, that Gurobi's internals will dominate the time/memory taken in this snippet. Out of curiosity: is there some benefit (i don't think it's available within gurobipy yet) in giving constraints in vectorized/matrix-form (instead of one-after-another; e.g. A <= B where A and B are matrices = basic library-design in modelling-tools like cvxpy although it's way different internally reasoning about convex.)? This should help somehow with efficiency internally, or not?

Comment: @sascha There are no real benefits. In practically every application, the solution algorithms require far more time and memory than the API.